# Отправка DateTimeOffset через HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

Столкнулся с проблемой в передачи времени на сервер написанный на WebApi. Подозреваю, что некорректно данные сериализуются в Json формат. Данные передаю в формате DateTimeOffset, клиент - простая форма на WPF.

Модель данных на клиенте (на сервере аналогичная, только с атрибутами для Id):

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset PhotoUploadDateTime { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Метод отправки

```
 private void AddUserClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileModel = new Person
        {
            //Id = new Guid(),
            Name = txtName.Text,
            LastName = txtLastName.Text,
            Department = txtDepartment.Text,
            PhotoUploadDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(image)
        };

        var client = new WebApiSender(urlAddress);
        client.AddPerson(fileModel);

        MessageBox.Show("File has been uploaded");
    }
```

Метод AddPerson HttpClient'а:

```
  public async Task AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Person>("api/employee/", person);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error when adding file!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Заполнение модели данных на клиенте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные которые пришли в контроллер и записываются в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге на сервер в контроллер приходят валидные значения, кроме времени и даты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Банально не внимательность. Свойство в модели имело другое имя, а атрибутами JsonProperty не покрывал.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Vasya","lastName":"Pupkin","department":"Programmer","dateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
```

Это отсылал сервер, а в модели клиента свойство было с именем:

```
public DateTimeOffset PhotoUploadDateTime { get; set; }
```

а не

```
public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
```